# python Selenium --headless argument triggers safety feature of the webside

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Im working on small project and im logging there in to quizlet. The problem is that when I run my program without any chrome driver options there is no problem it works perfectly fine. But where I add my arguments the quizlet won't let me login.
Those are my arguments:

```
CHROME_PATH = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\chromedriver.exe"
WINDOW_SIZE = "3840,2160"
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=%s" % WINDOW_SIZE)
chrome_options.binary_location = CHROME_PATH

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, options=chrome_options)
```

as you can see i get an error:
[here is a picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TP588.png)

when i edit this line:
`driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH)`

it works perfectly but i don't want to see the window.
I looks like '--headless' argument triggers safety features of the webside.
This is so weird. Any sugestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#options.headless = True
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument(
    "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Try using user agent , as headless uses a different useragent than normal

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug with Chromedriver, see the link below for an explanation from the Selenium team.

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/8967

I would monitor the Chromedriver bug tracker for any updates on the Headless mode bugs, see link below:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/list

Sorry for the non help...